# Nokogiri next element by type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

Say I have

```
<h3></h3>
<h2></h2>
<p></p>
```

How can I get to the `p` node from `h3`

Right now I can only get from `doc.css('h3').next_element` which doesn't take any arguments and returns the `h2` tag.

Is there a way to check node types recursively or is there a method where I can call for example `doc.css('h3').next('p')`

P.S Of course the HTML I'm parsing is not as simple as the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only one element (not collection), there is `at` method

And you need selector with [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) `~`

```
doc.at('h3 ~ p')
```

If you need collections of such `p` that go after each `h3` tag

```
doc.css('h3 ~ p')
```